# Locally mapped drive letters disconnect when network adapter is disabled

Tags: command-prompt

First question in this brilliant forum: I've been using map network drives for local folder links, which works fine. If I disable my network adapter, the drives show as disconnected. Is there any way to maintain these connections throughout any network adapter related event? Both CMD and windows shell methods seem to render the same limitation in this case.

BTW, Thanks to everyone for making this a valuable resource...

Comment: how would windows access your network drive if your network is down?

Comment: My issue here more specifically is that Windows doesn't seem to know when a link is local and hence doesn't need an active network connection to reach the location. Is this a group policy based solution? I've seen some articles on that method, but it appears more applicable to networks.